# How properly initialize a model to use the `get` function?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model, and when I do `model.attributes.model` I see the attributes of the model. One attribute is `name`, so `model.attributes.model.name` returns the right name. However, when I do `model.get('name')` I get the default that I had set in the model.

How do I set all the attributes of the model so that it works with `get`?

*JSON used to build the model*

```
[{
    "model":{
            "name":"My name",
            "description":
            "Description goes here!",
            "vote_score":null
    },
    "context":{}
}]
```

Comment: Why are you using `model.attributes.model.name`? `model.get('name')` should map to `model.attributes.name`.

Comment: I see my problem. The to_json method I used doesn't return the right json sequence. I should return an array of hashes like the value of "model" in the hash in the gist. I followed [thoughtbot's intro book](http://liquidmedia.ca/blog/2011/02/backbone-js-part-3/) and it looks like the json that is generated in the setup I have is wrong. I thought I followed it right. Or perhaps the version of Rails I'm using is wrapping it differently. The JSON I am feeding into the controller looks [like this](https://gist.github.com/2325408)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either modify your server-side code to return an array of model attributes, as you said in the comments, or modify your model definition to override the parse method :

```
var MyModel=Backbone.Model.extend({
   parse: function(data) {
      return data.model;
   }
});
```